# С помощью чего быстрее всего создать gui форму в windows?

Tags: gui

Используя какую среду разработки с каким языком программирования, можно быстро сделать приложение, которые бы общалось с субд, выводило таблицы, изменяло данные форм, имело дерево каталогов с неограниченным уровнем вложенности, кнопки, картинки и.т.д?

Сейчас у нас в excel есть разные данные в разных файлах, в большом количестве. Стало очень долго и неудобно там что то изменять, добавлять. Нужно быстро создать приложение с графическим интерфейсом и единой базой, чтобы с субд работать. 
Никак не могу выбрать конкретную среду и язык. Можете что нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: C# Visual Studio 2013, имхо, если не сишники, Delphi - она тоже умеет "хлоп-хлоп и в продакшн", и всякие там деревья каталогов есть. Но копаться в имеющихся типах что там, что там придется долго.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Бесплатная среда разработки [Visual Studio Community & Express 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)
- Язык C# или VB.NET
- Библиотека GUI - WinForms или WPF
- Библиотека для данных - ADO.NET/Entity Framework

Comment: Почему WPF никто не рекомендует? ;-)

Comment: Потому что и так жесть, если начинать...

Comment: В чем заключается жесть?

Comment: Мне кажется wpf после excel будет разрывом... Но могу ошибаться :)  Добавлю для полноты wpf

Comment: А WinForms по сравнению с WPF типа няшечка?

Answer (score 0):

Если знаете JavaScript то как вариант https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/
Плюс ко всему еще и кроссплатформенность.

Если нужно совсем просто то Microsoft Access + формы в нем, а можно и вообще без форм.

Comment: Только не Access :(

Comment: Ну я если честно его тоже не люблю :) Просто раз уж человеку нужно быстро сделать базу и интерфейс... Access к сожалению на первом месте... Но лично себе я бы ни за что на свете не стал бы его ставить :) Просто со всеми остальными вариантами много мороки  на начальном этапе...

Comment: Он был ужасен еще 15 лет назад...

Comment: Ну дык майкрософт же... Но Вы считаете что человек, который тут интересуется на чем лучше писать (т.е. не знает нормально ни одного языка) сможет на чем то другом сделать что-то лучше? ЗЫ: если бы знал какой-то язык, я думаю он сразу бы сказал из чего выбирать...

Answer (score 0):

Раньше с этой задачей справлялось Delphi / C++ Builder, но как там сейчас обстоят дела даже не знаю. Все остальное требует каких то начальных усилий чтобы что то начать делать.

Comment: И каких же таких усилий требует всё остальное, каких не требовалось в делфи? о_О

Comment: В остальных так просто по быстрому накидать на форму не получится чтобы получить результат.

Comment: Да ну? И что же там сложного? Winforms C# / VB.NET.

Comment: WinForms без напильника не взлетит.

Comment: winforms как раз взлетит без всего.

Comment: Это ж MFC только для .NET-а ;-)

Comment: о_О Это никаким боком не MFC. Совсем. Даже на плюсах, хотя там .net какой-то страшный.

Comment: По уровню развития не далеко от MFC.

Comment: Совсем неправда.

Comment: Я бы не сказал: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws8s10w4.aspx

Comment: MFC до сих пор существует отдельно. Winforms гораздо проще.